# TURN server, TLS on port 5349 doesn't work

Tags: webrtc, turn

I've set up my turn server, and tested on [IceTricklePage](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/).
The non-secure port 3478 works just fine, I can gather a candidate with type "relay".
But with the secure port (TLS) 5349, it always failed.
The server turn:xx.xx.xx.xx:5349?transport=tcp returned an error with code=701.

Below is my turnserver.conf file:

```
# /etc/turnserver.conf

# STUN server port is 3478 for UDP and TCP, and 5349 for TLS.
# Allow connection on the UDP port 3478
listening-port=3478

# and 5349 for TLS (secure)
tls-listening-port=5349
external-ip= xx.xx.xx.xx
listening-ip=0.0.0.0


allow-loopback-peers
no-multicast-peers

min-port = 49152
max-port = 49365
verbose

# Require authentication
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
# We will use the longterm authentication mechanism, but if
# you want to use the auth-secret mechanism, comment lt-cred-mech and 
# uncomment use-auth-secret
# Check: https://github.com/coturn/coturn/issues/180#issuecomment-364363272
#The static auth secret needs to be changed, in this tutorial
# we'll generate a token using OpenSSL
#use-auth-secret
# static-auth-secret=replace-this-secret
# ----
# If you decide to use use-auth-secret, After saving the changes, change the auth-secret using the following command:
# sed -i "s/replace-this-secret/$(openssl rand -hex 32)/" /etc/turnserver.conf
# This will replace the replace-this-secret text on the file with the generated token using openssl. 

# Specify the server name and the realm that will be used
# if is your first time configuring, just use the domain as name
server-name=turn.mydomain.com
realm=turn.mydomain.com
#

# Important: 
# Create a test user if you want
# You can remove this user after testing
user=user:password

total-quota=100
stale-nonce=600

# Path to the SSL certificate and private key. In this example we will use
# the letsencrypt generated certificate files.
cert=/etc/coturn/turn_cert/turn.mydomain.com/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/coturn/turn_cert/turn.mydomain.com/privkey.pem

# Specify the allowed OpenSSL cipher list for TLS/DTLS connections
cipher-list="ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384"

# Specify the process user and group
proc-user=turnserver
proc-group=turnserver

# Log file path
log-file=/var/log/turnserver.log
simple-log
#syslog
```

I also config my router to port-redirect any transport to public xx.xx.xx.xx:5349 to the internal server running TURN server (similar to the way I did with 3478).

Below is the config:
[image]

Anyone get an idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 5349` to see whether connecting successfully or not. If you got `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` then your network config is incorrect and need to be changed. [Here](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/issues/678) is something related